# How to Git push to staging server and exclude one file

Tags: git

Inside my application I do have a server.inc file which contains a switch statement `$server=1` that specifies the server the app is installed in.

Now everytime I git push to staging or production that file also gets transfered and I have manually to update the variable on the entire cluster.

I know I could simply exclude this file from git, but then I would not have it under version control.

How could I overcome this problem? Is there a way to exclude a secific file from the hook or something similar?

Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual technique in this case is just copy this file with the name `server.inc.example` or `server.inc.template` - anything that makes you think it's a documentation and not a real production file. After that you commit `server.inc.example` and delete original `server.inc` from the repository and also add it (`server.inc`) to `.gitignore`. Now you only need to walk through your cluster for the last time and set up `server.inc` files with required values there (or setup some deploy hook, YMMV).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to exlude single files from a push, because git push works with commits not single files. Once you added/committed a file, it will be pushed.

However, you can make a little workaround forcing git to mark a file as unchanged or changed as you like. This way you can edit contents but tell git not to track the updates:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>

git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```